# How to ensure that the Columns in different controls have the same size?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here's my code:

LabelTexUserControl user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="LabelDoubleTextBox.LabelTexUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LabelDoubleTextBox"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid  IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="LabelGroup"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="ValueGroup"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Label,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:LabelTexUserControl}}}"  Margin="5"/>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Value,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:LabelTexUserControl}}}" Margin="5" />
    </Grid>

</UserControl>

    public partial class LabelTexUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public LabelTexUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Label), typeof(string), typeof(LabelTexUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

        public string Label
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(LabelProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Value), typeof(string), typeof(LabelTexUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

        public string Value
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

MainWindowVM

```
public class MainWindowVM
{
    public string VMValue => "This is a value";
    public string Terrify => "Dont be terrify";
}
```

MainWindow control

```
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowVM/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <local:LabelTexUserControl Grid.Row="0" Label="My Label" Value="{Binding VMValue}"/>
        <local:LabelTexUserControl Grid.Row="1" Label="Warning...... but I am just super loooong... lalala" Value="{Binding Terrify}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Note that depending on how uniform the length is for different `Label` ( or `Value`), the `MainWindow` won't look aligned on the UI. I try to use `ShareSizeGroup`, but apparently it doesn't work across controls.

Is there anyway to fix the above code, so that the `Label` and `Value` column looks uniform, regardless of how many `LabelTextUserControl` I define in `MainWindow`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `IsSharedSizeScope="True"` from the `LabelTexUserControl` if you want the different instances of the control to share the same size scope:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="LabelGroup"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="ValueGroup"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Label,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:LabelTexUserControl}}}"  Margin="5"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Value,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:LabelTexUserControl}}}" Margin="5" />
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that _and_ remove the ShareSizeGroup="LabelGroup" from MainWindow.xaml

Comment: Now it works, any idea why `IsSharedSizeScope="True"` is unnecessary and screwing things up?

Answer (score -1):

You can set columns width dynamically like below:

```
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

It means the total size is 100%, 50% for first column, 50% for second column.